# How can I read a file in chunks based on custom delimiter string?

Tags: rust

I have a large file looks like this:

```
<doc>
Hello
</doc>

<doc>
World
</doc>

// Some more repeating blocks
```

I want to read this file in chunks, and read only a section of it at a time, delimiting with `</doc>`. So I am expecting getting these in the first chunks:

```
<doc>
Hello
</doc>
```

And these in the second chunks

```
<doc>
World
</doc>
```

I have tried reading the doc related [BufRead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html), but then [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until) can only accept a byte as delimiter. How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: are they always in separated lines?

Comment: What order of magnitude is the size of this file? If it's small, you'll have better luck reading the whole thing into memory and then chunking the string after it's loaded. If it's significantly larger, then a streaming solution is warranted.

Comment: @Netwave Yes they are always in separated lines.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The size of this file is about 400MB at the moment, and it will continue to grows overtime

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an ideal one-size-fits-all solution to this problem. If you don't want to use a standard XML parser, here are some tips...

If you expect your chunk to always end with `</doc>` in a separate line, you can simply read via [`read_line()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) and check each line (maybe also `trim()` it before comparing it). If `</doc>` is not necessarily alone in a line, you can still use `read_line()` but with some extra code that parses the line. Those ideas, however, might not be suitable if you expect your XML to have gigantic lines.

Also, if you expect (and want to add support for) nested `<doc>` tags, that might complicate your manual parsing additionally.